# What is the computation relative time?

Tags: performance, matlab, process

What is the computation relative time for many computation process?
If many computations are processed on Matlab and the time elapsed are measured,
what is the best way to make a comparison between them in the sense of relative time without the need to mention about the processor speed or the seconds?

Comment: It's very difficult to 'normalize' benchmarks this way, so most people just mention times in addition to hardware details used for testing. The reason this is so hard is because the hardware is so complex. DRAM access might take 60 cycles on one machine and 100 cycles on another in spite of both being Intels, e.g. A newer generation machine might do a better job with branch prediction as another example. None of this is very 'stable' so the hardware details become extremely relevant. So most people just stick to very coarse algorithmic complexity or just hardware details+time metrics.

Comment: for the reason you mentioned above, I want to use relative time and not absolute time, without going into details about the machine. I'm just not founding the way to mention the reference the other relative time.  let say 3 process computed in matlab with  these computation time 100, 150 and 230. in order to write the computation time I wanted to say their computation is 1, 1.5 and 2.3. scientifically how it is posssible to write them and to make the reference.

Comment: Unfortunately I think you generally have to go into those machine details if you want something a bit more granular than algorithmic complexity. The problem is that if you look at the time required to do something like a conditional branch or a memory load/store, it's a _variable_, not a constant, and it varies based on machine and even dynamic environment factors within a single machine. You could go into details like how many memory accesses are involved, branches, arithmetical operations, etc. but there's generally not this clean, universal kind of metric you want because of the variables.

Comment: It's also why profilers are so important in performance-critical areas. How fast does this code go? Even the guys at Intel often can't predict it very easily, so they run profilers over the code to spot those micro-level hotspots, count cache misses, DRAM accesses, look at disassembly, branch mispredictions, etc. It's an extremely complex process, so most people writing algorithmic papers focusing on benchmarks just go into very precise details of the hardware involved for testing along with absolute times measured.

Comment: Or perhaps I misunderstood what you meant by relative. If you're comparing your algorithm to another's, you can normalize that to percentages, for example or plot it in a graph. However, even then, your hardware details are very important to mention along with those absolute times measured, because your algorithm might run faster than another on your machine, but it's not guaranteed to be the same on another hardware.

Comment: exactly, I'm running 10 different algorithms on my machine and I want to make a comparison between them on prediction performance and time consuming. so I don't really care about the exact time they consume. what I can't do is hot to write these numbers in scintafic way without going into details to the machine, I'm plotting this comparison on a graph as well

Comment: Unfortunately the details of the hardware still matter here a lot and it's why normalized benchmarks like this comparing algorithms are still very careful to mention to precise testing conditions (the exact hardware used, operating system, etc), since those details matter no matter what given how machine/environment-dependent performance is.

Comment: considering that I'm going to mention the hardware part, what is the best way to define the time offset and the relative time ?

Comment: It's kind of up to you. You can get some ideas looking at the benchmarks of formal papers like this: http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/ReadingSeminar/Papers/Shi06.pdf or this http://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.2137.pdf. Tables are popular as well as graphs and charts. Most just stick to absolute times as a lowest common denominator, but you can include relative percentages as a nicety, e.g. to see how the absolute measurements relate to each other more easily if you're using a table, for example, rather than a graph/chart.

Comment: For example, if you are comparing bubble sort to quicksort, bubble sort might be assigned 100% since it's the slower algorithm with the absolute time at the top of the range, and you can show the relative percentage of quicksort compared to bubble sort. It's really in the realm of nicety here: the formal parts that are critical are the absolute times and the testing conditions (ex: hardware details and the inputs used).